# How to get php request URI without context path?

Tags: php

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns URI with context path.

For example, if the base URL of a website is `http://localhost:8080/sitename/` (i.e. the context path is sitename), and I use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for `http://localhost:8080/sitename/portfolio/design`, it will return `/sitename/portfolio/design`.

I am then exploding the result to interpret my clean URLs:

```
$page=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$segments=explode('/',trim($page,'/'));

$sitePage = $segments[1];//portfolio
```

This is working fine for my local testing environment, but on the production server, `$segments[1]` must become `$segments[0]`

In order to use the same code in development and production, is there any way to get only this part `/portfolio/design`, i.e. the URI without context path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use virtual hosts so your test site will be on:

```
http://sitename.localhost:8080/
```

That way absolute paths (relative to the web-root) will be the same on the test server and the production server.

The how-to depends on the test server you are using.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by comparing `SCRIPT_NAME` and `REQUEST_URI` like this:

```
// /sitename/index.php
$path = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], '/'));

// /sitename/portfolio/design
$uri  = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));

foreach ($path as $key => $val) {
    if ($val == $uri[$key]) {
        unset($uri[$key]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

// portfolio/design
$uri = implode('/', $uri);
```

I'm guessing you have .htaccess routing to index.php

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that is the way to do what you wanted - get some part of the URI.

I would suggest you set up a virtual host (assuming you're using Apache), either Name or Address based. Then you could have something like http://127.0.0.42/portfolio/design or, with some editing of the *host* file on your system even http://sitename/portfolio/design. Then your developing environment will resemble the production one.

Hope that helps.